# Python GraphWin Stops Responding With Winsound

Tags: python, audio, graphics

Everytime I run 'RyTunes.py', the sound plays, however, while it plays the window stops responding. Anyone know why?

Code: https://gyazo.com/01fb9808b54a8f0cb052e98f66e1f392

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I simply swapped the "SND_FILENAME" flag to "SND_ASYNC" so that the thread would not stop.